# JSF: invoke method if conversion fails

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

In JSF, how can I invoke method in case of conversion failing on any of input fields? I guess I can write my own converters and do all the stuff there, but isn't there a more simple way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `PreRenderViewEvent` listener, and in that method check if validation has failed. This listener method will be called every time just before the view is rendered.

E.g.

Consider the following Facelet:

```xml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
>
    <h:body>

        <h:messages/>

        <f:event listener="#{onErrorBean.onPreRenderView}" type="preRenderView" />

        <h:form>
            <h:inputText value="#{onErrorBean.test}" label="test" required="true" />

            <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{onErrorBean.onSuccess}" />
        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

And the following backing bean:

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class OnErrorBean {

    private String test;

    public void onPreRenderView() {
        if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isValidationFailed()) {
            onError();
        }
    }

    public void onSuccess() {
        System.out.println("Success!");
    }

    public void onError() {
        System.out.println("Error!");
    }

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

}
```

If you press the button without entering a value you'll see "Error!" being printed in your console, enter a value and you'll see "Success!".